# changing date fromat from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date-formatting

So I know this question has been asked a couple of times over, but I believe my situation is a bit different (happy to be proven wrong of course!)

Here is the data flow: a user types a date in a date in a form. They then click a button. My macro then takes that date, runs it through the following function:

```
    Function AddWeekDays(StartDate As Long, Days As Long) As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim d As Date

    d = StartDate
    i = 0

    While i < Days
        d = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), Day(d) + 1)
        If Weekday(d, vbMonday) < 6 Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend

    AddWeekDays = d
End Function
```

Then it formats the date to change it from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in the following way:

```
Dim deadline As Date
Dim deadline_formatted As Date
Dim DateReceived As String
Dim DateConverted As Date
DateReceived = txt_DateReceived.Text
DateConverted = Format(DateReceived, "dd/mm/yyyy")
deadline = AddWeekDays(DateValue((CStr(DateConverted))), 9)
deadline_formatted = Format(deadline, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

However, the `deadline_formatted` value is still coming out in the mm/dd/yyyy format.

As an example, when a user enters 01/05/2017 the program should return `deadline_formatted = 12/05/2017`, but it returns `deadline_formatted = 05/12/2017`

I have tried changing the variable type to string to see if that made a difference (it didn't), and have tried directly converting the deadline variable to the required format by using the following code:

```
deadline = Format(AddWeekDays(DateValue((CStr(DateConverted))), 9),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

which still returns the incorrect format.

Can anybody out there suggest either:

- How to fix the formatting issue to get the deadline_formatted into the format dd/mm/yyyy 
  OR
- suggest a "workaround" to flip the "dd" with the "mm" (not ideal obviously, but if it works, it works!)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/

Comment: `deadline_formatted` is a `Date`, not a `String`, so it isn't "formatted" in any particular way (it is simply the number 42867).

Comment: What date format would the user normally use on their computer?  To be honest, I'm not sure why you are trying to change that format around - you should let them enter a date in whatever format they are used to, and then store the date in an Excel cell (if that is where it is going) as a Date.  That way, whatever users look at the workbook will see the date in whatever format they are used to seeing dates, and any calculations based on the date will work correctly without having to make all sorts of weird adjustments to convert from one locale to another.

Comment: The `Format()` function returns a string, so when you assign it back into a `Date` it would be like doing `CDate(Format())`. If you need the output to be in a certain format, either format the container, or put it into a formatted string.

Comment: @YowE3K - I completely agree with your last comment. the user is currently entering the date format in the format as they would normally use, however, for some reason our company computers are localised in the US with the mm/dd/yyyy format (which is odd as we are an Australian based comapny) hence whenever the date is placed in the cell, it goes in as mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: It sounds like your PCs are set up to use a US date format (Control Panel / Region and Language / Format).  Your company would be better off if they allowed you to change them to English (Australian) format instead - it would allow you to avoid formatting dates as text, which causes the spreadsheets to be useless when viewed outside Australia.

Comment: @YowE3K exactly the issue i have raised with them they are following up now. I have tried it on a computer with the proper settings and it works fine, so if you want to put your comment as the answer, you can have your 10 points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is to actually change your computer's default date/time format to match the method used by the users.  (In comments it is stated that the users are Australians but your company is US-based, so the default is probably currently set to be the USA's "mm/dd/yyyy" format.)

By ensuring that the computers date/time format is correct, it will allow you to process a date as a Date, and it can be stored in Excel cells as a Date, which then allows any of the Australian users to see it displayed as "dd/mm/yyyy" format while a USA-based colleague would see it displayed as "mm/dd/yyyy".

There is a financial risk to your company caused by forcing users to interact with software using an unfamiliar date system, as accidental entering of dates in the wrong formats can lead to major errors downstream, so it is in the company's best interest to allow you to change the settings to be relevant to the users.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly related to your problem, however I believe it might fix your issues. The manual calculation of adding week days might be the problem here.

There is a built in function to add [workdays](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/WORKDAY-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33). You can include/exclude weekends/holidays. The following code replaces your above mentioned code.

```
Sub AddWeekDays()
    Dim deadline As Date, deadline_formatted As Date
    deadline = txt_DateReceived.Value
    deadline_formatted = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(deadline, 9), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    'debug.print deadline_formatted
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the result to be String.

```
Dim deadline As Date
Dim deadline_formatted As String '<~~ change string
Dim DateReceived As String
Dim DateConverted As Date

txt_DateReceived = "01/05/2017"

DateReceived = txt_DateReceived
DateConverted = Format(DateReceived, "dd/mm/yyyy")
'deadline = AddWeekDays(DateValue((CStr(DateConverted))), 9)
deadline = AddWeekDays(CLng(DateConverted), 9) '<~~ change Long
deadline_formatted = Format(deadline, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother about the regional settings. Instead, make sure that all dates are captured as Date() or Now() values (42123 or 42123.5555). On the output side such values can be presented in any format you wish.
To ensure that dates are entered correctly my preferred way is to use a date picker. If that can't be done make no rules for entering the date at all, working on the presumption that each user will know how to enter a date on his/her machine. Add a date check, like ISDATE(), which will catch some input errors but not all. You don't need to catch all. You only need to teach users how to input dates on their respective PCs.

Answer (score 0):

With this line you don't need anything else.

```
Range("E:E").TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
'1.2.2019 -> 01/02/2019
'2,3,2019 -> 02/03/2019
'3-4-2019 -> 03/04/2019
'4*5*2019 -> 04/05/2019
'5_-6-*2019 -> 05/06/2019
'and so on
```

Of course you can change the format with

```
xlMDYFormat
```